# repo : fatal: cannot create directory at 'pathtools/testdata/escapes/**': Invalid argument / > rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred

Tags: git, github, rsync, repo

I'm trying to create an AOSP image intended to be run on the Nvidia Jetson Nano platform. To to this,I need to clone the repo from this page :

https://github.com/antmicro/kvm-aosp-jetson-nano

According with the tutorial,these are the commands that should be issued :

Fetch and install the repo tool

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

Fetch the AOSP sources

mkdir aosp
cd aosp
repo init -u https://github.com/antmicro/kvm-aosp-manifest.git -b kvm-aosp
repo sync
```

.......

the problem is that at some point I see this error message :

```
error: unable to create file pathtools/testdata/escapes/*: Invalid argument
fatal: cannot create directory at 'pathtools/testdata/escapes/**': Invalid argument
error: Cannot checkout platform/build/blueprint: GitError: Cannot initialize work tree for platform/build/blueprint
Updating files: 100% (595/595), done.
Updating files: 100% (12659/12659), done.
```

and the download FREEZED. I would like to know how to fix this. thanks. I'm using ubuntu 20.10 and this version of repo :

```
root@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/ziomario# repo --version
<repo not installed>
repo launcher version 2.12
       (from /usr/bin/repo)
git 2.27.0
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20) 
[GCC 10.2.0]
OS Linux 5.8.0-44-generic (#50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 9 06:29:41 UTC 2021)
CPU x86_64 (x86_64)
```

As u can see below,there are some special characters inside this folder :

[image]

I think that repo sync is not able to get them from the server. I have the same problem when I try to copy the whole repository from from a place to another one on my disk using this command :

```
sudo rsync -avxHAX source destination
```

In this case the error is this :

> rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous
> errors) (code 23) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.2.3]

its happened one time only that I've been able to copy the whole repo from the server without getting errors. So I have those characters correctly copied on my disk. But I can't copy them to another place of my disk and when I try again to clone the repo,it always give the error. I think that's an odd behavior and I want to understand the reasons behind this.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem while trying to sync with a different android manifest. The drive I was trying to sync to was formatted in ntfs (mounted in linux via udisksctl).

To ensure compatibility with windows systems udiksctl (or whatever tool your installation uses manage mountpoints) mounts ntfs filesystems with the `windows_names` option which blocks any files with symbols not supported by windows.

Try remounting your drive without this option.
For example:

```
umount /dev/sdx
mkdir /mnt/ntfs
ntfs-3g /dev/sdx /mnt/ntfs
```